# mySQL server won't start

Tags: mysql

I am trying to start the mySQL server that I just set up on my mid 2010 MacBook Pro, but when I go to System Preferences > MySQL > Start MySQL Server to start it, it will only start for a second and then stop. I think I  might have narrowed down the problem to the permissions of the server.

[image: current server permissions]

My colleague and I believe that the way they are set, the "staff" has no access to the write permissions and somehow this is not allowing the server to start up properly. I would go in and change the settings, but my computer says I am not allowed to change it. Is there a way to fix this problem or is there another possible cause?

Comment: what is the log showing? (btw, why just not use MAMP? It configures your mysql automatically for you)

Comment: Agreeing with @nick here. Check the log that mysql generates it will almost definitely have the specific error noted which will remove all the guess work.

Comment: I'm not completely sure. I went to my Macs log files under var/log and none of them seem to be from mySQL which is weird because I have mySQL and have tried to start the server multiple times already.

Comment: @ Nick, thanks for telling me about MAMP. It seems that I can access my mySQL server using it.